# The principle of converting image with bit 8 into image with bit 16 automatically in Mathematica

Tags: import

I import a collagen image that is 8-bit depth but when I checked image properties in Mathematica, it shows that it is 16 bit. My code is shown below. I found that Mathematica always imports image as 16 bits by default so I used `Import["Roi 1 a0.tif", "BitDepth" -> 8]`. However it seems that this setting did not change the bit depth of this image in *Mathematica*. Does anyone know what happens when importing image into *Mathematica*?

```
Collagenimage = Import["Roi 1 a0.tif", "BitDepth" -> 8];
Import["Roi 1 a0.tif", "Summary"]
ImageType[Collagenimage]
```

[image]